# Firebase not adding user swift 3

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift3

This was working, but for some reason it isn't working now. I'm trying to create an account and put a user in the database, but all that it is adding is to the authentication tab and not to the database. I put break points on almost every line of my code and only 2 of them get hit and my print statement with "SHEEEEETTT" is NOT being printed. Any ideas on why this is happening?

Here's my code:

```
Let dataBaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference(fromURL: mydatabaseurl)

////breakpoint hits
FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: emailText.text!, password: passwordText.text!, completion: { 
            (user, error) in

            print("SHEEEEETTT")

            if(error != nil){
                if let error = error as? NSError {
                    if error.code == 17999{
                        print("ERROR invalid email address")

                    }else{

                        print("ERROR \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                }


            }else {

            guard let uid = user?.uid else {

                return
            }

                print("user created")

                let usersRef = self.dataBaseRef.child("users").child(uid)
                let values = ["email":self.emailText.text!, "password": self.passwordText.text!,"name": self.nameText.text!,"type": self.type]
                //note: autheticate image with NSUID().UidString
                usersRef.updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { (err,rf) in

                    if err != nil {

                        let errorAlert = UIAlertController(title: "\(err)", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
                        let okay = UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

                        errorAlert.addAction(okay)

                        self.present(errorAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

                        print("ERROR \(err.debugDescription)")

                    }

                    print("saved user")



                })


            }

        })//breakpoint hits
```

Comment: Is *SHEEEEETTT* being printed?

Comment: @Dravidian no it's not. None of my print statement are being printed

Answer (score 0):

iF *SHEEEEETTT* is being printed and you are using one email per person feature then try to write data like:-

```
 FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users/\(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid)").setValue(values, withCompletionBlock: {(Err,SnapRef) in

        if Err != nil{

              //Show alert

            }else{

          print("User Created")

        }
    })
```

If this still doesnt work, try printing **`FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid`** and check if you are getting the info

Comment: Sheet is not being printed.

Answer (score 0):

I am very *skeptical* of this line

```
let databaseRef = FIRAuth.auth()?.database().reference
```

I tried it in my own project and `auth` doesn't have a database object and even their [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/FIRAuth) proves this. Plus it makes sense since Firebase wants these two modules totally separate from one another i.e. authentication and database.

If you are trying to get the database reference,

1. Make sure you've imported either `Firebase` or `FirebaseDatabase` module in your respective VC
2. `let databaseRootRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()`. This will give you reference to the root node. You could also use the `reference(fromURL: )` or `reference(withPath: )`. More [info](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDatabase)

Comment: I added that in later and I added it wrong. I'll update my question to make it more accurate.

Comment: Have you tried printing `FIRAuth.auth.currentUser` to see if it holds any information?